# what tools or languages or How can i build the site like google news

Tags: web-crawler

I have to build the website where i need to crawl to filter or u can say read the 50 webistes.
then after reading those webistes i need to filter the news e,g news related to Mercedez benz and then i need to display that on that webiste with refrence to original source.

Basically what google news is doing

Currently i know PHP and can build complex websites in that. But i have no idea about how to read other websites. and i don't know how to proceed , i mean which things i need to learn before attempting to make site. or i can dive the site straight way.

Please help , how should i proceed

Comment: You may want to look at python, or a functional language, it may make it easier to build this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Google News (like a lot of Google stuff;-) is in a mixture of C++, Java, and Python, plus Javascript on the front-most part too -- but there's no reason you should use all or even any of these excellent languages (well, you *will* want Javascript if you need highly interactive user experience with your site, of course;-); just about any language makes it easy to do web crawling.  For example, for a web crawler in PHP, see [this tutorial](http://vision-media.ca/resources/php/create-a-php-web-crawler-or-scraper-5-minutes)!